# Sony Xperia M4 Acqua insufficient memory

Tags: insufficient-memory, sony-xperia

I recently bought a Sony Xperia M4 Acqua device. Its memory is only 8 Gb large, so I installed an SD card. The problem is partially solved, since I get messages from various apps that the memory is unsufficient for certain functions. Any ideas of how I can deal with this?

Comment: Have you checked the Tag-Wiki info from the insufficient-memory tag? [Lots of information there](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info)

Answer (score 0):

Move apps to the SD Card. That worked for me. (I had the *exact same problem*)!